# Is there any way to set up a different Pytest configuration for different folders / subfolders in the Pycharm project

Tags: pycharm, pytest

in my PyCharm project I have some pytest files, that I have to run with "environment variables", and other files can't run with this option.
At this point, every time I want to run a test file, I have to edit environment variables for it, which is a pain.

Is it possible to set a certain configuration for the files in some location (also in folders that contain them), and another for other folders?

Comment: You can put autorun fixtures in `conftest.py` files on different levels that set or remove the environment variables.